# SQL Query: Favorite product in a certain timeframe

Tags: sql

I have a school assignment that requires me to answer the following questions:
 - What was the favorite product (highest quantity) in a specific timeframe?

*Now my SQL DB is designed as followed:*

```
[Order] Number (PK), Date, Time

Orderrule Number (FK), Time (PK), Productnumber (FK), Quantity
```

Theres more tables but i don't think i need more information for this query. I'm honestly clueless on how to get this info. Could someone point me in the right direction? To make myself clear, i'm not looking for someone to post the answer, but rather to point me to the right knowledge to answer it myself.

Comment: what database you use ?

Comment: i'm using access 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you,

```
select top 1 r.Productnumber,sum(r.Amount) from Order as o
left join Orderrule as r on o.Number = r.Number
where o.dbDateTime between @sDate and @eDate
group by r.Productnumber
order by sum(r.Amount) desc
```

Comment: that would give me the product thats most often seen within the table orderrule, but it not doing anything with the 'amount' attribute.

Comment: Oh! you said "most ordered" does it depend on maximum amount?

Comment: Excuse me for the confusion. I'm looking for the product with the highest 'amount' value.

Comment: Instead of sum use max

Comment: I've changed my questions, i'm not looking for the highest amount of product purchases on a single order rule but in total. So from all orders how many pizza's did i sell.

Comment: So much confusion! again i have changes ans, SUM is used. It should work